# Kubernetes: how to run application in the container with root privileges

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, root, privileges

I setup kubernetes with master and node on the same hardware (ubuntu 18) using this [tutorial](https://powerodit.ch/2017/10/29/all-in-one-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm/).

Kubernetes 1.15.3
docker 19.03.2

The container I created runs an emulation software that needs root privileges with write access to /proc/sys/kernel directory.  When kubernetes start the container I get an error inside the service script /etc/init.d/myservicescript indicates that it can't write to /proc/sys/kernel/xxx.  The container runs on ubuntu 14.

I tried to set the "runAsUser: 0" in the pod's yaml file

I tried to set "USER 0" in the Dockerfile

Neither work.  Any suggestion on how to get this working?

Comment: If you need to access `/proc/sys/kernel` then your program can’t really run in Docker or Kubernetes, since it’s demanding the ability to take over the whole host.  There are limitations on what even root can do.

Comment: David Maze: The container doesn't have its own /proc/sys/kernel?  If not, how can each container operate as if it is run on real OS?

Comment: Docker is not a full virtualization system and all containers share the host’s kernel and associated host-kernel settings.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the user inside the container does not give you any privilege on the host. In order to get elevated privilege, you must set `privileged: true` in the security context.

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    args:
    - sleep
    - "999"
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

Comment: I will give this  a try. However, I thought the /proc/sys/kernel is within the container space.  If it is the host's then I cannot run multiple instances of the same container because they all write to the same /proc/sys/kernel/xxxx

Comment: privileged is not supported.  I got: error validating data: [ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.containers: got "map", expected "array", ValidationError(Pod.spec.securityContext): unknown field "privileged" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSecurityContext]

Comment: My apologies, I edited my answer. While you can set `securityContext` at both the `spec` level and `spec.containers` level, the `privileged: true` flag is only supported at the `spec.containers` level.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out.  Now it passes that error.  Still get another error that I need to find out why.  Thanks Alassane